# Can't use comma as separator c3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, c3.js

I'm currently working on a evolution graph with the framework c3.js based on d3.js.

I want to format the values of the Y axis that are numbers. I currently have this format : XX.X
What I want is to use the comma as separator of decimals : XX,X

I tried two methods :

```
y : {
            tick : {
                values : steps, 
                format : d3.format(",.1f")
            },
            min : steps[0],
            max : steps[steps.length-1]
         }
```

And to use the d3 formatter :

```
 y : {
                tick : {
                    values : steps, 
                    format : function(d) {
                        var s = d3.formatSpecifier("f");
                        s.precision = precisionFixed(0.1);
                        s.comma = true;
                        var f =  d3.format(s);
                        return f(d);
                     }
                },
                min : steps[0],
                max : steps[steps.length-1]
             }
```

See doc here: https://github.com/d3/d3-format

But I get an error (d3.formatSpecifier is not a function...). Does someone already resolved this issue?

Thank you

Comment: [tag:c3.js] is not compatible with D3 v4. The [doc of c3](https://github.com/c3js/c3) says: `Dependency
D3.js ~3.5.0`.

Comment: Hi, Ok I understand that that way is not the correct one in my case. Does somebody have another idea regarding this comma ?